# How make a dynamic array using void** and void*?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, dynamic

I want to make a dynamic memory array function where in the arguments I can put in any type I want, the count, and the item I want. I've been googling and looking at YT videos, but none of them explain how to do just THAT, and when the item I want is a pointer. For example, I would have this:

```
struct Entity
{
   int health;
   int level;
   int experience;
   char* name;
}

Entity** entitylist = NULL;
int entitycount = 0;

Entity* CreateEntity(/*args for creating an entity*/)
{
   Entity* newentity = malloc(sizeof(Entity));
   // All of the entity creation stuff and at the end...
   AddItemToList(&Entity, &newentity, &entitycount);
}
```

I know in the function I want to create I would need to pass in references to the specific list, but from that I'm pretty much clueless. I've tried to use malloc and realloc but either crashes the program or does nothing. And would new and delete work for this type of stuff?

And how would removing something like this work? I haven't seen anything on the internet yet about removing an item from a list, only adding them.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you in C or C++? They are very different languages with very different best practices for this kind of thing.

Comment: Yep, pick a language and folks will probably point to a dozen libraries that will do it.

Comment: C++ sorry. Although I am also fine with C stuff.

Comment: Then what should I use if I can't use pointers?

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with using `malloc` in C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a double pointer for a data type such as `int**` with give you a dynamic 2D array, or a dynamic array of pointer objects, depending on your implementation, and a single `int*` is just a normal dynamic array. To full instantiate and allocate the memory for these, here's how you do it:

1D Dynamic array:

```
int* arr;
arr = new int[SIZE];
```

2D Dynamic Array:

```
int** arr;
arr = new int*[SIZE]; //<- stop here for 1D array of pointer objects
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    arr[i] = new int[SIZE2];
```

Comment: Thanks. But how would I remove something from the array. Would I iterate through it and do delete on all of the pointers?

Comment: @CNJMC1 if you're simply trying to reset or change a value in it, you can just iterate or call an assignment if you know the exact index and set to NULL to "empty" the index. If you were to call delete, you would remove the pointer itself from memory, possibly causing segmentation faults when iterating through in the future, until your reinstantiate the position with a new pointer

Comment: And how would I make it so that the 2D dynamic array would work for all data types, even some of my own?

Comment: @CNJMC1 the concept is the same for all data type, including self-made classes, just change `int` to your class or desired data type. For example, for a personal class called `Car`, to make a 2D array of `Car` instances you do... `Car** cars; cars = new Car*[SIZE]; etc.`. If you're talking about a dynamic array that will support ALL data types, I'm afraid that just doesn't exist, each array can only hold ONE data type of values.